# Sending User input from python to php

Tags: python, php, python-requests, get, http-post

**This is my python file:**

```
host = socket.gethostname()

mac = hex(uuid.getnode())

sign = host + mac
message = input('plz enter message')
userdata = { message, sign}
url = "http://localhost:8081/project/server.php"
resp = requests.post(url,  data=str(userdata))

print(resp.text)
```

**This is my PHP Script:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['userdata'])){
    $userdata = $_GET['userdata'];
    echo $userdata;
 }
else{
     echo "Data not received";
 }
echo $userdata ;
?>
```

**Problem**
my python file is not sending userdata to php script. Any help would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: I have tried all possible solution available on internet and also tried alternative of requests urllib and urllib2.

Comment: im not a python dev, but have you tried sending query strings instead? `server.php?userdata=hello-world` like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are sending post data but in PHP script, you are capturing GET data.
We can re-write both files like this to send POST data and capture POST data

**Python file**

```
sign = host + mac
message = input('plz enter message')
url = 'http://localhost:8081/project/server.php'
postdata = {'sign': sign , 'msg' : message }

x = requests.post(url, data = postdata)

print(x.text)
```

**PHP file**

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['sign'])) {
    $myfile = fopen("data", "a");
    $sign = $_POST['sign'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    echo $sign . " " . $msg ;
    fwrite($myfile , $sign.','.$msg."\n");
    fclose($myfile);
}
else {
    echo "Data not received <br/>";
}

$myfile = fopen("data", "r");

while(!feof($myfile)) {
    echo fgets($myfile). "<br/>";
}
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: browser is still showing "Data not received"

Comment: Are you using a browser or python script to send data ?
what is the output of python script ?.

Comment: python script is showing what i need it is showing correct output but i want to pass this output in php and want to store it in a text file or database from php script.

Comment: I edited the PHP code for save and display the saved data

Answer (score 0):

`requests.post` needs `dict` object, not `str`.

So posting data with requests,

```py
data = {'userdata': message}
resp = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Edit

```py
data = {'userdata': message}
resp = requests.get(url, params=data)
```

Comment: I didn't notice that php script requires "GET" request.  Edited code.

Comment: again no success.@pu2x

Comment: this what i received in browser . " Data not received"